# Yii CListview -> pagination and AjaxLink/ajaxButton

Tags: yii

I have problems regarding with pagination and Ajax form.

Here is my code for `Controller`:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
        'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>10,
        ),
));

$this->render('users',array(
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
));
```

For view -> users:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_user',
```

);

For render _users:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink($text, $this->createUrl('admin/deleteuser',array('id'=>$data->iduser)), array('success'=>"js:function(html){ alert('remove') }"), array('confirm'=>_t('Are you sure you want to delete this user?'), 'class'=>'delete-icon','id'=>'x'.$viewid));
```

if i have 15 rows in a database it will only show 10 and will generate a pagination (ajaxUpdate = true) for next 5. The first 10 rows has no problem with the ajaxLink because the clientscript was generated but problem is the when I move to the next page, the ajaxLink is not working because its not generated by the pagination .

any idea? thanks

Comment: you have to **explain** what is wrong, rather than just put code and expect answers

Comment: where is the description of what you are facing?

Comment: sorry i thought I already put the problem.. sorry again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate method, check this [post in the yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/17160-solved-new-member-question-ajaxlink-inside-a-clistview/page__view__findpost__p__85177). So your code will become like this:

```
echo CHtml::link($text,
    $this->createUrl('admin/deleteuser',array('id'=>$data->iduser)),
    array(// for htmlOptions
      'onclick'=>' {'.CHtml::ajax( array(
           'beforeSend'=>'js:function(){if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"))return true;else return false;}',
           'success'=>"js:function(html){ alert('removed'); }")).
         'return false;}',// returning false prevents the default navigation to another url on a new page 
    'class'=>'delete-icon',
    'id'=>'x'.$viewid)
);
```

Your confirm is moved to jquery's `ajax` function's `beforeSend` callback. If we return `false` from `beforeSend`, the ajax call doesn't occur.

Another suggestion, you should use `post` variables instead of `get`, and also if you can, move the ajax call to a `function` in the index view, and just include calls to the function from the all links' `onclick` event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes i just read that and I think i have no other options so I created something out of that idea.. just put codes on afterAjaxUpdate

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure, but given past experiences I think the problem is in the listview widget itself.

If the owner of the widget is a Controller, it uses renderPartial to render the item view.
Renderpartial has, as you may or may not know, a "processOutput" parameter which needs to be set to TRUE for most of the AJAX magic (its FALSE by default).

So perhaps you can try to just derive a class of the listview and add a copy in there of    "renderItems()". There you would have to change it so that it calls renderPartial with the correct parameters.

Comment: when I click the next page and since it's ajax I saw the result in the console (firebug) and I saw that the ajaxLink jscode was generated but still it's not working on the parent document.

Comment: Most ajax link stuff requires some "on document ready" code to bind to the event etc, it's that that is not added to the returned result with the processOutput == FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

In the widget Clistview, I added afterAjaxUpdate

```
$jsfunction = <<< EOS
js:function(){
    $('.delete-icon').live('click',function(){ 
      if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?'))
      {
        deleteUrl = $(this).attr('data-href');
        jQuery.ajax({'success':function(html){ },'url':deleteUrl,'cache':false});
        return false;    
      }
      else
        return false;
    });
  }
EOS;

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  'id'=>'subscriptionDiv',
  'itemView'=>'_subscription',
  'afterAjaxUpdate'=>$jsfunction,
  'viewData'=>array('is_user'=>$is_user,'all'=>$all),
  'htmlOptions'=>($dataProvider->getData()) ? array('class'=>'table') : array('class'=>'table center'), 
  )
);
```

and in the _user just added attribute data-href

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink($text, $this->createUrl('admin/deletesubscription',array('id'=>$data->idsubscription)), 
            array('success'=>"js:function(html){ $('#tr{$viewid}').remove(); }"), 
            array('confirm'=>_t('Are you sure you want to unsubscribe?'), 
                'class'=>'delete-icon',
                'id'=>'x'.$viewid,
                'data-href'=>$this->createUrl('admin/deletesubscription',array('id'=>$data->idsubscription))                
                )); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
   'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
   'itemView'=>'_user',
   'enablePagination' => true,
);
```

if this doesn't solve, try including the total number of records in the data provider options as -

```
'itemCount' => .....,
```